# WordPressでAJAX通信したデータをlaravel側のheader.blade.phpに表示する

Tags: laravel, ajax

WordPress側からAJAX通信したデータ(headerとfooter)をそれぞれlaravel側で表示したのです下記のソースコードで出来ません。どこで間違っていますでしょうか？

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src=""></iframe>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
let ajaxUrl = 'https://example.jp/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxUrl,
    data: {
        action: 'get_header',
    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(ID + ":" + password));
     },

    success: function( data) {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('myiframe');
          iframe.contentWindow.contents = data;
          iframe.src = 'javascript:window["contents"]';

    }
});`
```

Comment: 現在、質問者とは別のアカウントから編集の提案が成されています。このアカウントが質問者さんと同一人物のものである場合は、[間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) をご覧下さい。

Answer (score 0):

結論としては、

```
iframe.contentWindow.contents = data;
```

ここが

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = data;
```

又は

```
iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = data;
```

だと思うんですが、状況（今回は通信先のサーバはそこが返すコンテンツの内容）によってはリスクのある実装なので、

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Security/Types_of_attacks

この辺りを一通り読んで頂いてから試してみてください！